# GetAssets from application context in android

Tags: android, assets

is it possible to use getAssets using Application instance like:

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
    static private MyApp    sInstance = null;

    public static MyApp Instance()
    {
        if( sInstance == null )
        {
            sInstance = new MyApp();
        }

        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

and in function use:

```
*** AssetManager as = MyApp.Instance().getAssets();
Fonts.ARIAL     = Typeface.createFromAsset(as, "Arial.ttf" );
```

Manifest:

app_name is "MyApp"

The getAssets function call returns NullPointerException (*** line)

How do I fix it?

Well found the answer:
MyApp should be like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication singleton;

    public MyApplication getInstance(){
        return singleton;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
    }
}
```

Please have a look inside :
http://intridea.com/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android?blog=company

Comment: Please confirm, 1. you add the MyApp inside AndroidManifest.xml, 2. you have a static reference for MyApp and assigning that inside the onCreate or constructor of the MyApp class. 3. inside the Instance() method you return that.

Comment: Please see the edit. I guess that the getAssets() function inside an applicationContext should not be used? Maybe it has some limitations

Comment: Found the problem - you gave me the correct direction to follow